# Ecommerce and Vespa: filtering customer's wishlist

Tags: vespa

Let's suppose an ecommerce site has wishlisting functionality. Some users wishlist a lot of products (on a scale of tens of thousands). Total amount of products is in millions. We want to implement functionality where a customer can filter those products like in catalogue.

When we looked into implementing this using Elasticsearch, the best way we've found was using [terms lookup](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup). Like, we create a document for each user's wishlist, and then filter out products we need using this document. After that all filtering/etc is done regularly. The problem here is that Elasticsearch cannot sort those products properly — i.e. how document specifies it, since we want to sort by wishlisting time.

This is when I decided to look into Vespa. But after reading documentation I still have no idea what's the best way to implement this. This looks like a problem needing "join" to my rdbms-infected mind. :)

Cardinalities of data is like so:

- millions of products
- hundreds of thousands of users
- tens of thousands of wishlisted items

So... any ideas how to implement or pointers on what to read?

Answer (score 2):

In Vespa you need two document types for this (if you want to store the wishlist in Vespa that is, it's not a requirement)

- Retrieved the whislist for given user, either from Vespa using get api of Vespa or from another storage solution.
- Retrieve and rank using DotProductItem over the product id field along with a ranking profile.

```
/search/?yq=select * from products where dotProduct(product_id, {"a":3, "b":2});&ranking=wishlist&hits=10
```

In this case a is a more recent product in the wishlist then b. ranking profile to go with it:

```
rank-profile wishlist {
  first-phase {
    expression:rawScore(product_id)
  }
}
```

You can also use WAND to speed up the search and retrieve only the most recent/top ranking hits in the wishlist. The above example retrieves all and ranks all.

See

- https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/query-language-reference.html
- https://docs.vespa.ai/en/using-wand-with-vespa.html

Comment: Is the second `dotProduct` argument always specified inline? Since if it is, then it's a bit like passing all wishlisted product ids to Elasticsearch...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a WeightedSet item where the item tokens are an id of the products and the weight is the timestamp you want to sort by, see https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/query-language-reference.html#weightedset, or see https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/multivalue-query-operators.html#weightedset-example to create it in a Searcher (recommended).

To rank by the timestamp, use a rank profile which just ranks by the match weight, e.g attributeMatch(name).totalWeight

(Regarding sorting, you could also just retrieve *all* the matches in a Searcher, resort in code, remove those below the fold and then fill() with the summary data. That will scale fine to a few tens of k as long as you do it before filling.)

Comment: I read up on WeightedSet and it seems like that example with Searcher passes data about sorting from backend to Vespa... Is there no way to pre-store those weighted items in separate document type or something like that?

Re-sorting on backend is weird since it'll break on "big" customers (which have north of 100k wishlisted items...)

Comment: In the way I suggested here (before the section in parenthesis), there's no resorting - you really sort by the weights. But they must be sent at query time, yes. You could avoid that by storing all user's wishlists on all nodes (a global document) and importing the weighted set field into the product documents. That might be a better option depending on the number of nodes, and total amount of wishlist data.

Comment: So if I understand that correctly, then importing field is possible from a parent (or a global) document — which doesn't sound too good considering there are a lot of users, right?

Comment: Right, you either need to send the data to all nodes at query time or distribute it to all nodes at write time.

Comment: ... but for others reading this, note that you can here get away with passing a lot less than all the data at query time: Just sort the wishlist first and pass the N first items in it. N should be higher than the number of items left after filtering, which is generally not known, but you can keep exponentially increasing it until you get enough. When it becomes large it means you have a strong filter and it will be cheap to ask for all and sort after retrieval instead (but importantly before fill()!). This can be done quite easily in a Searcher.